# Angular 4 approach to query native DOM element properties?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, components

Lets dive straight to the point:

[image]

I have this stacked cards gallery, where the first card (thats on top of the other 2 cards) will show the profile of the person), and all other cards that is at the back will not show the profile.

Below is the `ngfor` that prints the card like so:

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" [ngForOf]="peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets" let-first="first" let-last="last" let-i="index">
  <app-card 
    [class.currentCard]="first" 
    [@myAwesomeAnimation]="_state[i]" 
    [prevCard]="first ? person.previous : null" 
    [currentCard]="person.current" 
    [nextCard]="first ? person.next : null" 
  ></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

When you click on next button, the **`[@myAwesomeAnimation]`** will be called, where it will update the:

1. `height`
2. `z-index` (where 3 is at the front, 2 is in the middle, and 1 is at the back)
3. `left`.

I need to be able to show profile when the card is at the front, and hide it if the card goes at the back. Like shown in the image, but the current implementation on shows it when `first` is true. But when you click next, the first is actually pushed back - so technically it wont be front anymore.

One approach was to really get the `z-index` of the card using elementRef, but I really want to avoid using that approach.

Is there "Angular 4" way of going about this?

Thanks

## Update

To give you more info. look at my `animation.ts`

```js
export const animations = trigger('myAwesomeAnimation', [

  state('moveCurrentToBack', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px)',
    height: '167.3px',
    left: '60px',
    opacity: 1,
    zIndex: 1
  })),

  state('moveNextToCurrent', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px)',
    height: '239px',
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 3
  })),

  state('movePrevToNext', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px)',
    height: '203.15px',
    left: '30px',
    zIndex: 2
  })),

  transition('* => moveCurrentToBack', animate('700ms ease-out', keyframes([
    style({
      offset: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.25,
      opacity: 0.75,
      transform: 'translate3d(-5%, 0%, 0px) rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.50,
      opacity: 0,
      transform: 'translate3d(-10%, -30%, 0px) rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.75,
      opacity: 0,
      left: '66px',
      height: '150.3px',
      zIndex: 1,
      transform: 'translate3d(0%, 30%, 0px) rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 1.00,
      opacity: 1,
      left: '60px',
      height: '167.3px',
      transform: 'translate3d(0%, 0%, 0px) rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg)'
    }),
  ]))),

  transition('* => moveNextToCurrent', animate('500ms ease-in', keyframes([
    style({
      offset: 0,
      left: '30px',
      height: '203.15px'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.1,
      left: '24px',
      height: '203.15px'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.25,
      left: '18px',
      height: '213.15px'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.50,
      left: '12px',
      height: '223.15px'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.75,
      left: '6px',
      height: '233.15px'
    }),
    style({
      offset: 1.00,
      left: '0px',
      height: '239.15px'
    }),
  ]))),

  transition('* => movePrevToNext', animate('500ms ease-in', keyframes([
    style({
      offset: 0,
      left: '60px',
      height: '167.3px',
      zIndex: 1
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.1,
      left: '54px',
      height: '167.3px',
      zIndex: 1
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.25,
      left: '48px',
      height: '177.3px',
      zIndex: 1
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.50,
      left: '42px',
      height: '187.3px',
      zIndex: 1
    }),
    style({
      offset: 0.75,
      left: '36px',
      height: '197.3px',
      zIndex: 1
    }),
    style({
      offset: 1.00,
      left: '30px',
      height: '203.3px',
      zIndex: 1
    }),
  ]))),
]);
```

In here, the cards are being moved based on the state.

Let me rephrase my question.

I need to get the zindex of the card without using elementRef. Is there any alterntaive to elementRef?

Comment: This information is not enough to understand your problem. Either provide a  working relevant plunker or explain it with more code.

Comment: @micronyks Ive updated my question. Please check above.